# WPF CanExecute depending on more that one factor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, canexecute

I am facing a dilemma in using the `CanExecute` parameter in `CommandBinding` for the menu in my application.

The situation is following: the application itself can run in certain modes, e.g. the working mode, review mode, etc. Depending on the mode, some menu items should be enabled or not (hence, should be possible to execute or not).

What I've done until now is create 4 event handlers for CanExecute:

```
private void Mode1CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e);
private void Mode1CannotExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e);
private void Mode2CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e);
private void Mode2CannotExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e);
```

as some menu commands are common to both modes, some are exclusive to each mode.

As the application develops, there are more factors determining whether a particular menu command should be executed at the moment. The solutions I can think of are:

- adding a boolean multibinding to `CanExecute` event handler, but I couldn't find any examples of this solution, I believe it is not possible.
- adding more event handlers for `CanExecute` with even longer names, what will actually make the code less readable
- have "per menu item" `CanExecute` event handler and base the code for each event handler on some boolean variables to determine the result of it

I know that enabling the menu item can be done in `SubmenuOpened` event handler, but for many of the commands there is also a `KeyGesture` defined.

**My question is:** what would be the best practice in this case, so the logic of the application (command execution availability) is guaranteed but also the code readability stays on reasonable level?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Well what I do - is I always have 1 `canexecute` method per command
This way it's simple and consistent and You know where to look for problem

Another point to have it in 1 method - is just pure testability and readability.

Very simple to test then

```
public bool CanExecuteGoCommand(){
 if (xxx)
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}
```

and the method can be as big as You want, with as many If's as You need with a million conditions, modes, variables ect..

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you that it is simple and consistent, provided you started with such an approach. 

Our starting point was a menu with something like 50 `MenuItem`s, where some were applicable to one mode of the software. Thus, creating one `CanExecute` event handler and apply it to applicable `MenuItem`s. 

I believe it is time for refactoring of the application.

Comment: I had a similar problem with "application modes". At the end of the day - it's just a single static variable accessible in whole application. then You can use it anywhere.. in any 'canExecute' ect.. this way all you need is 1 event, appMode changed - and a simple event handler in Your VM - onAppModeChaged += () => {RaisePropChaged("appMode");}

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use an implementation of DelegateCommand or RelayCommand as your ICommand property in your ViewModel. Either of these will allow you to pass a Func into the constructor of the ICommand instance as the 'CanExecute' delegate. When you pass this Func in, you could include other properties of your ViewModel as closures, and therefore access them in the delegate. This will allow you to combine your CanExecute parameter with any other member in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you, Dean. I'll give it a try and share the results.